# How to stop Spring boot Jpa from adding foreign key constraints to the database views on the startup?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, view, constraints

In my Spring boot web application there are several views that define as entity model. In the startup of this application, many exceptions are thrown like below:

```
GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table view_staff add constraint FK7qgsdfanumdw1ji68 foreign key (type_id) references stafftype" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table view_staff add constraint FK7qgsdfanumdw1ji68 foreign key (type_id) references stafftype" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:526) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:452) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
```

This is one of my view models:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "view_staff")
public class ViewStaff  {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private StaffType Type;
}
```

How I could prevent spring boot from adding foreign key constraints to those views?

Comment: Show your entity classes

Comment: I added it to question body.

Comment: Don't let Hibernate manage your database schema, use something like FLyway to do that. Spring Boot by default has schema generation disabled when using something else as H2, so you explicitly enabled it, disable it. You also want to mark your entity as readonly/immutable (slighty better performance).

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the problem by letting Hibernate also **create** the tables.

If you stay using the table schemas originally created by Hibernate the *Alter-Table-Problem* does not occur.

One has to be careful when dumping data from one DB into it (e.g. on restore from an older version). This may overwrite the original schema ending up in an *Alter-Table*-command on every startup again.

Answer (score -1):

Because you dont tell Spring what is the the id to join the column to, it creates one default of its own that does not exists:

```
(type_id) references stafftype
```

Add:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name="staffType_id", nullable=false)
private StaffType staffType;
```

Make sure you have the completeing code on StaffType:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="staffType")
private Set<ViewStaff> ViewStaffs;
```

Check out [this](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many) for more info